# CSS buttons is unclickable depending on the size and margin (mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I'm making a responsive website from desktop to mobile. I'm focusing now in doing the mobile but then encountered a problem, which is my css buttons. For some reasons they can be clicked in some format but can't be on the size and margin format I want. Also, I didn't encounter this when doing it the normal screen size. Anyone have a solution for making it clickable for the size I want?

Here is the CSS:

```css
.article.container {
  padding: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex.container.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: all;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.tab-selections {
    width: 29%;
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    height: 200%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0em;
    color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 1em;
    border-left: 0.6em solid;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.tab-selections:hover {
    background-color: rgb(205, 221, 255);
    color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
}

.active {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(205, 221, 255);
    border-left: .6em solid;
    border-left-color: rgb(87, 0, 255);
    text-align: center;
}

/* for Mobile */
  @media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    .article.container {
        padding: 0em;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .flex.container.parent {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .tab-selections {
        height: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0em;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
 }
```

Here is the HTML (ReactJS):

```html
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="article container">
      <div className="flex container parent">
        <NavLink className="tab-selections" to="/sample/article">
          ARTICLES
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="tab-selections" to="/sample/casestudies">
          CASE STUDIES /<br />
          WHITE PAPERS
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="tab-selections" to="/sample/news">
          NEWS/EVENTS
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className="a-content-flex">
        <div>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/sample/article"
            component={InsightHomeSummaryArticles}
          />
          <Route path="/sample/casestudies" component={CaseStudies} />
          <Route path="/sample/news" component={News} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! So, what I did was remove the padding from the ".article.container" then changed it into margin-top! Thanks for the help!